# How to differate between different event types

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, american-english

I am trying to translate a part of a web application and I am unsure which describes the situation precisely. The context is theatre.

1. event: for a public audience a performance of a theatre performance
2. event: only "interal audience" like the actors etc. e.g. used in internal trainings or trips or rehearsal

Which words would you use? Currently, I use for the first one Event and would like use this for second one, too. But I think, unique naming is important.

Comment: If 1 is only used to refer to public performances I would probably use "Public Performance". Whereas 2 needs something more generic, I'd probably use "Internal Event".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest *activity* for the internal events.

Answer (score 0):

The **opening** performance is usually the first performance, available to the general public, in the play's final form.

Before the opening, most plays give **rehearsal** or **pre-opening** performances to make adjustments to the staging, script, musical score, etc.  Audiences are usually invited to gauge audience reactions.

Comment: I think he's looking for a general word to cover all these different things, to use in the UI for a scheduling application.